# How to use SSL in JSP(in a Java EE application )?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, ssl, openssl, websphere

I am creating a web app using Java EE and JSP. I am using Tomcat and WebSphere Application Server as server app.

I want to implement my web app in SSL, so it show https:// and have secured site icon.

How to created a Java EE web app with SSL encryption on Both tomcat and WAS.

Answer (score 1):

Get an SSL certificate and install it on your server.  (Your ISP should be able to help,)  If properly installed, all you need to do is change from HTTP to HTTPS.

You may want to check to see that any access is through HTTPS.  One way is to check it within your JSP.  Try the following snippet:

```
if (!request.getScheme().equals("https") 
{
    //  throw an error something... 
}
```

Otherwise your code should work with either HTTP or HTTPS.

ADDENDUM:  If you want to create your own self-signed certificate, check out [MobilFIsh openSSL](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/openssl/openssl_quickguide_code_examples.html) or Google "JAVA openssl"